# Qt - QTreeView horizontal scroll bar never shows up when items hit the edge of the bar

Tags: qt

I have a file hierarchy that is shown in a QTreeView. But when I expand all the expandable items and they hit the edge of the scroll bars. Only the vertical one works.

[image]

These lines of code didn't make any changes.

```
connect(view, SIGNAL(expanded(const QModelIndex&)), this, SLOT(makeVisible(const QModelIndex&)));

void Hierarchy::makeVisible(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    view->scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible);
}
```

Comment: Is your [horizontalScrollBarPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) set to `Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded` ?

Comment: @Cendolt yes I did

Comment: Have you tried setting the [textElideMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#textElideMode-prop) to `Qt::ElideNone` ? (even if I'm not sure it would make a difference...)

Comment: @Cendolt nah it's not working

Comment: Where is the tree view header?

Comment: Is the header necessary?